# Having the background color on the whole width but keeping some padding left right

Tags: html, css

I have a test website here: http://test-minimalist.weebly.com/#bbienfaits

The background color (green for the second page) is not filling the whole width because of the container class which is 960px.

If I set this container to width = 100% my background color is filling the whole space. That's perfect but another problem appears: the text is also taking the whole space but I prefer having some padding left and right.

So I tried to put `padding: 0 100px;` on this container but then the background color is no more filling this space.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: you have some mistake in css code on web site, not relevant for this question:  .tall-header-page, .short-header-page, .no-header-page, .landing-page{bbackground: #222121 }. double "b" in background

Comment: I know that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.container` width. Add width to `fp-tableCell`

```
.container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: auto;
}
.fp-tableCell {
 display: block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another div inside your container which will have a margin instead of padding and then just set the background-color to the container.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container"></div>
</div>

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.inner-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested: using the child element (id: wsite-content which is below my container class) to set `width: 80%;` and `margin: 0 auto;` but keeping the same problem: the background color is no more filling the whole space.

Comment: Then your problem must be elsewhere. Look at the comment to your question, does that solve the issue?

Comment: @Bronzato The problem is that your container doesn't have a background-color, so setting a padding 100px will cause a white background. Also your inner container is only 1720px wide so it won't take up the full space.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code .itz works 
  .container
{
width:100%
}

.paragraph
    {
    position:relative;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    }